# Ubuntu 19.04 on USB fails to boot

Tags: boot, usb, acer

I installed a full Ubuntu 19.04 on a USB (booting from another USB with the installer on that second USB) since I want a portable OS with me.

I try to boot from the first USB (the one with full Ubuntu installed to it) which fails; even if I remove all drives from that [Acer Predator G9-593](https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Document/User%20Manual%20W10/User%20Manual%20W10_Acer_1.0_A_A.pdf?acerid=636350268906854925) laptop, the PC gives a "No Bootable device" prompt. The firmware/BIOS setup is set to try booting from USB first.

Edit:It worked, Oldfred's solution seems to fix it, thanks guys for your help.

Comment: In the firmware configuration (aka Bios Setup) is this computer enabled to boot from a USB device?

Comment: "To activate the BIOS utility, press F2 while the computer logo is being displayed." as per Page 50 of your manual: https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Document/User%20Manual%20W10/User%20Manual%20W10_Acer_1.0_A_A.pdf?acerid=636350268906854925

Comment: Ubuntu normally in UEFI boot mode installs boot files into /EFI/ubuntu on first drive usually sda or first NVMe drive. In BIOS mode installs to  MBR of first drive. But UEFI (or BIOS) has to boot from external drive if you want it portable. And Acer may have entries in UEFI as unknown as with all Acer you have to set "trust". You need to have an ESP on external drive to boot in UEFI mode. and to just boot from internal drive you need "trust". http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: _Lucifer Arina_, suggest you delete your 2 comments; if more comments appear, older comments can get pushed off-screen. I've edited their content into the Question for you. Anyway, when you have something to say, it should go in the Question by [edit] since you've got your hands on the problem.